# Not able to add shared library in WebSphere 8.5

Tags: websphere, shared-libraries

Using Websphere 8.5.5 admin console, I created a Shared library pointing to my Jars (Goto Environment -> Shared Library and follow the process mentioned in the WebSphere documentation). I then navigation to Application->WebSphere enterprise application and select my application. In the References section, I click "Shared library references". I select my application and click "Reference shared libraries". On the Shared Library Mapping page, I get my Shared library in the list of available libraries. I select the available library and click the right arrow button. The selected shared library is NOT getting added to the Selected box.
Anybody seen this issue? How do you resolve it?

Comment: Update: From the discussion on the IBM developer forum (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=3fe7e16b-4848-4f69-afcb-26bfb06f9d9b), I gathered that this is a known bug and the fix was available in WS 8.5.5.5. I upgraded my installation to WS 8.5.5.11 but am still running into the same issue.

Comment: Update: I got this working. I switched to Firefox and it worked fine. I was using IE earlier. It is probably some Java security issue. But switching browser works!

Comment: I just had the same issue. I was viewing the admin console through the RAD browser. When I looked up the admin port and logged into the console from Chrome, I was able to add the shared lib.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, select your Library file from the "Available" box, by clicking on it, if the selection is in blue colour, then it is selected or else if the selection is grey in colour, press Upper Key so that it gets blue in colour. Now, click right arrow button to add it in the selected box.